# Finding the solution to homogeneous linear equations with constant coefficients.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is what it says in my textbook, with no further detail as to why this is:
$$L(x) \equiv x^{(n)}+a_1x^{(n-1)}+\cdots+a_{n-1}x'+a_nx=0.$$
$$a_1 ,a_2,\ldots,a_n \in \mathbb R$$

According to Euler we search for the solution in the form of: 
$$x=e^{\lambda t}, \lambda \in \mathbb R$$

Does anyone know why this is exactly ?

Comment: here is a baby case x'+x=0. What're possible solutions to this differential equation?

Comment: Could you maybe go into a little bit more detail?

Comment: I understand how to solved to the first and second degree, but from then on, it gets different to me..

Comment: "Why?" as in "how?" Theoretically looking at it.

Comment: take successive derivatives of $x= e^{\lambda t}$, how are they all related?

Comment: Do you have trouble seeing that $e^{\lambda x}$ IS a solution or do you have trouble understanding where $e^{\lambda x}$ comes from?

Comment: where it comes from

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this particular function is the only nontrivial solution to the system. Obviously x=0 is a solution as well. You can show that, if you include an initial condition, that the system will have a unique solution and it will exist for all t. You can ALWAYS turn an nth order linear equation into a system of n-1 equations in a very easy way. From this, you can for your solution as a sum of exponentials. It is a neat idea to turn this problem more or less into a problem involving linear algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An heuristic argument :

The $e^{\lambda t}$ are eigenvectors of the operator $L$, so it's natural to see if one of them is an eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue 0.

They are indeed eigenvectors because

$$L(e^{\lambda t} ) = e^{\lambda t} \underbrace{ \left( \lambda^n + \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \lambda^{(n-k)} \right) }_{\gamma\in \mathbb{R}}$$

Comment: I feel silly opening a new question to understand the following: If we look at $e^{\lambda t}$ as a function of two variables, $\lambda $ and $t$. It says: In accordance to the rules of differentiation of functions of several variables, the following equation applies: $L(\frac{\partial ^m}{\partial  \lambda^m}e^{\lambda t})=\frac{\partial ^m}{\partial  \lambda^m}L(e^{\lambda t})$

Comment: What rules am I not seeing here?

Comment: @JimLowe : here $\lambda$ is a parameter, it's not very interesting (in my opinion) to see $e^{\lambda t}$ as a function of two variables. But, about how you get this equality, it's just that $$\frac{\partial^k}{\partial t^k} \left( \frac{\partial^m}{\partial \lambda^m} f(\lambda,t) \right) = \frac{\partial^{m+n}}{\partial \lambda^m \partial t^n } f(\lambda,t)  = \frac{\partial^m}{\partial \lambda^m}\left( \frac{\partial^k}{\partial t^k}  f(\lambda,t) \right) $$